# How to upgrade PowerBuilder code?

Tags: migration, powerbuilder

I have code from PowerBuilder 5 that can't be built. The compiler just stops before it is done without any error codes.

I would like to upgrade the code to the recent version of PowerBuilder but there are some intermediate versions of PowerBuilder that have binary dependencies to an old Microsoft java dll that Microsoft no longer can distribute due to some court case.

So, is there a way to get my code running in a newer environment?

/johan/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to use "intermediate versions of PowerBuilder" to migrate up to a current version, so even if this java DLL dependency sounds questionable to me (at least it doesn't ring a bell), it's irrelevant unless it affects the target version of PowerBuilder.

For migrating, you might want to check out this [migration guide](http://www.techno-kitten.com/PowerBuilder_Help/PowerBuilder_Migration/powerbuilder_migration.html), as well as a [list of changes to PB](http://www.techno-kitten.com/Changes_to_PowerBuilder/changes_to_powerbuilder.html) that may affect you.

Answer (score 1):

Very unusual sounding problem.  You could give a try to migrating the code to a more recent version of PowerBuilder and see if it will compile or at least fail but give you some useful error messages.

I would also recommend posting this in the PowerBuilder section of the Sybase newsgroups. They are very active and full of some brilliant PB minds with lots of experience.  You can find them here:  http://forums.sybase.com

Answer (score 0):

From here:http://forums.sybase.com/cgi-bin/webnews.cgi?cmd=item-4558&group=sybase.public.powersite

I just learned that the combination of "severe" message, and message
that psdwc70.dll was unable to self-register is probably because
msjava.dll is not present and/or registered on your machine.  The
psdwc70.dll file relies on msjava.dll in order to install properly.

/johan/

Comment: Actually, this message refers to *PowerSite*, not PowerBuilder. Some of the technology may apply to both products, but given how long ago PowerSite bit the bullet, I'd be surprised if that's true of current PowerBuilder versions. My expectation would be that you don't need to worry about this Java dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exporting the code in PB5 and importing in new version?