# Migrating PowerBuilder 6 program to PowerBuilder 10.5

Tags: migration, powerbuilder

Does anyone know a good way to go about taking a program made in PowerBuilder 6 and converting it to PowerBuilder 10.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the Migration assistant in 10.5 and see what it thinks of your code. Main thing to look out for going from 6 to 10.x is the switch to Unicode. Migration will handle most of it, but if you're calling external functions you'll have to tweak them. I think the Migration Assistant flags them.

Migration's been covered here a couple times. See [How to upgrade PowerBuilder code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164297/how-to-upgrade-powerbuilder-code) and 
[Migrating from Powerbuilder 6.5 to 10.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123941/migrating-from-powerbuilder-6-5-to-10-5) .

Answer (score 1):

Also, if your program is based on PFC, you will need to DL a newer version of the PFC from [here](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1058501), there is a sub project for the open source PFC.

Answer (score 0):

If your using PFC you also need to update it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).